# How can I swap the order of divs in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have two `div`s placed one after another in my html. I wan't to swap them.

```
<div class="1"></div> 
<div class="2"></div>
```

**I want to swap 1 and 2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you want to change the positions of you div.
>
> the code is simple but you need to **import jQuery** to your code.

```
<div class="www">
<div class="div1">first div</div>
<div class="div2">second dive</div>
</div>
```

> create a js file and use this jQuery code

```
$('.div2').each(function () {
        $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev('.div1'));
});
```

you cAN CHECK THIS CODEPEN link also

http://codepen.io/feizel/pen/egPBEz

Answer (score 3):

Use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) method when you want to move the element after the current element or use [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) method when you want to move the element before the current element.

```js
$('#a').before($('#b'));
// or
$('#b').insertBefore('#a');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert div 1 into a temp variable then remove it and insert after div 2.

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='div_1'>this is div 1</div>
<div id='div_2'>this is div 2</div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var temp = jQuery('#div_1');
 jQuery('#div_1').remove();
 jQuery('#div_2').after(temp);
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css flexbox to achieve this. wrap your divs in a parent container and apply flexbox to position them as you wish.

suppose you wrap your divs and then your html code is

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="first_div">first div</div>
 <div id="second_div">second div</div>
</div>
```

and your css code

```
.wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

#first_div {
height: 200px; 
order: 2;
}

#second_div {
height: 300px; 
order: 1;
}
```

though only disadvantage being you wont be able to use it in older IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox will be your friend if you're okay with alienating anybody still using [IE9 or older](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

You'll only need two lines of code on the container/parent div.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/Lzq7vpxn/